# vim iskeyword for latex

Tags: vim

I am using vim. I also asked this question on [vi-vim SX](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/12117/8748). I hope this question is acceptable for TeX-SX.

### Context

Currently, when I `set ft=tex`, my `set isk?` reads

```
iskeyword=@,48-57,_,192-255
```

that is, the default for vim.

### My "issue"

Currently, in a LaTeX string such as

```
$\abcde_\fgh$
```

the `w` jump would take me from the start to

1. `a`
2. `\`
3. `f`
4. `$`

Thus, the above setting does not feel very natural, nor optimal.

Indeed, it would probably be more reasonable to jump to

1. `\`
2. `_`
3. `\`
4. `$`

### My attempt

I'm thinking of something more like `set iskeyword=\,192-255`
so as to have words consist of characters that would fit in

- natural language words
- or LaTeX commands.

### Questions

1. Is it supposed to be so ? *yes, since it is the default*
2. What are better settings ?
3. How to properly set this variable for this filetype ?

Cheers,

Comment: `:h isk` suggests that `@,48-57,_,192-255` is the default for a non-Windows platform, and also that `iskeyword` can be ignored by a syntax file.  If you look in your runtime at `syntax/tex.vim` and search for `isk` you will see that it is indeed ignored by the standard TeX syntax settings in Vim.  So I don't think you need to worry about it.

Comment: Well, I *would* like to have it changed; something like `set isk-=_` and `set isk+=\ ` probably, but not too sure...

Answer (score 0):

Using `@` (meaning all alphabetic characters) is advisable, then 192-255 and other utf8 accentuated characters and ligatures should be directly included.

Adding or not numbers is a personal choice — maybe convenient not to, so if you have `$2ab$` and press `*` on `ab` you search for this and not `2ab`.

Adding `\` is probably a bad idea, because then `a\alpha` and `a\right` in `a\right)` will be a single word. As far as I am aware, it is not possible to add characters to `iskeyword` with a condition on their position in the keyword, which would solve that issue.

Finally, my settings for LaTeX are `set iskeywords=@,_`.